# How do I completeley remove everything on my machine relating to Spyder?

Tags: python, windows, spyder

This is on Windows. I long ago deleted Spyder from my machine using the add/remove program feature on windows. But this doesnt seem to remove anything, and there appears to be a lot of artifacts left over. When I type in Spyder in the search bar I get there is this remnant called "Spyder.exe" and that it is an app. I also have made a Spyder desktop app too, and it's just that generic looking python image with a white and blue background. So this isn't even a legit Spyder app anymore? When I click on it it loads up Spyder 5, when before I was using Spyder 2, odd.

So I want to know how do I completely, once and for all, remove/wipe **everything** relating to Spyder on my machine.

Thanks

Comment: Just locate where `Spyder.exe` is placed and remove the parent directory (or directories, not really sure) that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/443830/delete-all-files-whose-filenames-contain-a-particular-string

Try using this method. It will scan your files and delete certain ones only.

Comment: Thanks but how about in windows?

Comment: I do use windows myself so it should work.

Comment: I tried typing this into my terminal: ```C:\Users\PJ>find . -type f -name '*spyder*'```
File not found - '*spyder*'

Comment: Did you install spyder though a setup wizard?